# IntelliJ IDEA Selenium Plugin Run Configuration Exception: "Only local connections are allowed"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Selenium and trying to run a project with the Selenium Plugin for IntelliJ Idea Ultimate.
Any way I try to run the project this same exception pops up:

"Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 29665
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jul 29, 2020 4:48:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C"

I've imported webdriver.exe to the root project directory and I'm using all default configurations of a Selenium Project. This is the code im running:

```
`package org.example.selenium_test3;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MainPage {
    @Test
    public void openPage() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}`
```

I've tried adding ./ and .\ to the path, using an absolute path, and using the MainPageTest default class instead, all with the same results. Commenting out the "System.set..." line doesn't seem to do anything either. I haven't touched the default .iml and .xml files.
Any help would be appreciated, I can't figure this out.